# Where should I start for image processing?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new In ROS. I am working on a quadrotor, And I want to start image processing by ROS, in order to mapping,detecting faces, detecting objects and letters. I am looking for some tips and instruction to start it as a beginner.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/122451/where-should-i-start-for-image-processing-?/) by [ghazaleh](https://answers.ros.org/users/11236/ghazaleh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2014-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GeneralSpoonFul](https://answers.ros.org/users/8371/generalspoonful/) on 2014-01-26**:
What I want to know is how to send the image from the camera (some sort of publisher...) because I guess you don't do your mapping on-board the quad...

**Comment by [fatima](https://answers.ros.org/users/23862/fatima/) on 2015-12-11**:
hi i have a problem like you and now do you know how could we start? if you know please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For image processing you can use [Open cv](http://opencv.org/) that supported by ROS

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0